# JAVAFX linechart vs XYChart

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, linechart

I'm trying to add a linechart in my scene with JavaFX, however, when I use the constructor "new LineChart(Axis xAxis, NumberAxis yAxis) the data aren't shown inside the chart.

My code is described below:
LineChart defined in the fxml file, which is initialized in the controller

```
@FXML private LineChart<String,Number> lineChart;
```

Initialized the data:

```
XYChart.Series<String,Number> series = new XYChart.Series<String,Number>();
        
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String,Number>("Sample #1", 1);
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String,Number>("Sample #2", 2);
```

added data to the chart:

```
lineChart.getData().add(series);
```

In this case it works, but I can't adapt the yAxys to the data range. Due to this, i tried to do as follow:

```
        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(); 
 
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(); 

        lineChart= new LineChart<String,Number>(xAxis,yAxis); 

        lineChart.getData().add(series);
```

In this case the chart appears but it doesn't load the data.
Could you tell me what's wrong with it?
Thank you

Comment: You create a new `LineChart`: so now you have two of them (the one created in the FXML file, and the one you created in code with `new LineChart<>(...)`). The one created in the FXML file is the one that is displayed, but you add the data to the other `LineChart`. So you don't see the data.

Comment: Remove `lineChart= new LineChart<String,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);`.

Comment: Hello Greg, thank you for your help. I understand the problem, I thought it was a proper way to assign the X and Y axys to the FXML chart. I need to implement one of these solutions but to make the Y axys to automatically rescale to the data range. Is there a way to do it with the FXML linechart? Thank you

Comment: Aren't you defining the axes in FXML too? Just inject them into the controller the same way you do the `LineChart`, and call whatever method you need to call on them.

Comment: This was a really noobie thing from my side, now I've done it. Really thank you for your help. Wish a good evening